# fill not changing color of svg in Icon component

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to change color of svg by using "fill" but not working. Here is my component:

```
const Svg = styled.svg`
  vertical-align: -0.225em;
  color: inherit;
`;

const icons = [
  'accessibility',
  'attraction',
  'bathroom',
  'bedroom',
  'calendar',
  'car',
  'children',
  'cleanliness',
  'entertainment',
  'facebook',
  'filter',
  'general',
  'help',
  'instagram',
  'kitchen-dining',
  'leisure',
  'linkedin',
  'location',
  'map',
  'outdoors',
  'parking',
  'people',
  'policy',
  'pool',
  'privateRoom',
  'safety',
  'services',
  'sports',
  'star',
  'themes',
  'twitter',
] as const;

icons.forEach((name) => {
  require('./assets/' + name + '.svg');
});

export type IconName = typeof icons[number];

type IconProps = {
  className?: string;
  name: IconName;
  size?: number;
  color?: string;
};
 
export const Icon = ({ name, color, size = 24, className }: IconProps) => (
  <Svg
    className='logo'
    width={size}
    fill='red'
    height={size}
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
  >
    <use id="logo-svg" xlinkHref={`#${name}`} />
  </Svg>
);

export default Icon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `stroke` property instead of fill